# importing an svg icon in material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have this svg icon and I want to import that svg icon .
Here is the material ui code to convert that svg into an icon and finally using it .

```
let InstallIcon =
<SvgIcon>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M6 18c0 .55.45 1 1 1h1v3.5c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V19h2v3.5c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V19h1c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V8H6v10zM3.5 8C2.67 8 2 8.67 2 9.5v7c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5S5 17.33 5 16.5v-7C5 8.67 4.33 8 3.5 8zm17 0c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5v7c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5v-7c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5zm-4.97-5.84l1.3-1.3c.2-.2.2-.51 0-.71-.2-.2-.51-.2-.71 0l-1.48 1.48C13.85 1.23 12.95 1 12 1c-.96 0-1.86.23-2.66.63L7.85.15c-.2-.2-.51-.2-.71 0-.2.2-.2.51 0 .71l1.31 1.31C6.97 3.26 6 5.01 6 7h12c0-1.99-.97-3.75-2.47-4.84zM10 5H9V4h1v1zm5 0h-1V4h1v1z"/></svg>
</SvgIcon>;
export default InstallIcon;
```

import InstallIcon 
Now I am using this Svg icon inside material Ui bottom navigation .

```
        <BottomNavigation
          value={getIndexForRoute(pathname)}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          showLabels
          classes={{root:classes.root}}
        >
              <BottomNavigationAction  classes={{selected:classes.selected}} label="Trending" icon={<InstallIcon/>} /> // i don't see this InstallIcon working 
       </BottomNavigation>
```

Is this a corect way to create icons out of svg for material ui ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just have the SVG, CRA lets you do something like

```
import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from './icon.svg';
```

The SVG Icon component takes a path as it's child.

```
const MyIcon = (props) => (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
        <path d="M6 18c0 .55.45 1 1 1h1v3.5c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V19h2v3.5c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V19h1c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V8H6v10zM3.5 8C2.67 8 2 8.67 2 9.5v7c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5S5 17.33 5 16.5v-7C5 8.67 4.33 8 3.5 8zm17 0c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5v7c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5v-7c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5zm-4.97-5.84l1.3-1.3c.2-.2.2-.51 0-.71-.2-.2-.51-.2-.71 0l-1.48 1.48C13.85 1.23 12.95 1 12 1c-.96 0-1.86.23-2.66.63L7.85.15c-.2-.2-.51-.2-.71 0-.2.2-.2.51 0 .71l1.31 1.31C6.97 3.26 6 5.01 6 7h12c0-1.99-.97-3.75-2.47-4.84zM10 5H9V4h1v1zm5 0h-1V4h1v1z"/>
    </SvgIcon>
);

export default MyIcon;
```

You can also just take the SVG and export it as a component:

```
const MyIcon = () => (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M6 18c0 .55.45 1 1 1h1v3.5c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V19h2v3.5c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V19h1c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V8H6v10zM3.5 8C2.67 8 2 8.67 2 9.5v7c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5S5 17.33 5 16.5v-7C5 8.67 4.33 8 3.5 8zm17 0c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5v7c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5v-7c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5zm-4.97-5.84l1.3-1.3c.2-.2.2-.51 0-.71-.2-.2-.51-.2-.71 0l-1.48 1.48C13.85 1.23 12.95 1 12 1c-.96 0-1.86.23-2.66.63L7.85.15c-.2-.2-.51-.2-.71 0-.2.2-.2.51 0 .71l1.31 1.31C6.97 3.26 6 5.01 6 7h12c0-1.99-.97-3.75-2.47-4.84zM10 5H9V4h1v1zm5 0h-1V4h1v1z"/>
    </svg>
);

export default MyIcon;
```